# Como comparar 2 arrays e retornar os valores iguais dentro delas?

Tags: javascript

> 2. (INNER JOIN) Faça um algoritmo que receba o nome de dois jogadores e após isso peça 5 números de 1 a 10 para cada jogador.
>      Primeiro para o jogador A e depois para o jogador B. Após a escolha de
>      cada jogador o algoritmo deve apresentar quais foram os números iguais
>      que o jogador A e B colocaram. EX: Jogador A : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 Jogador B
>      : 1,2,3,8,7 Algoritmo imprime : 1,2,3

```
var rs = require('readline-sync')

    var a = []
    var b = []

    var nome1 = rs.question('Digite o nome do primeiro jogador : ')
    var nome2 = rs.question(' Digite o nome do segundo jogador : ')
    console.log('Digite 5 notas de 0 a 10 para o Primeiro jogador :')
    for(i = 5; i > 0 ; i--)

     { var nota = rs.questionInt('Nota : ')
     a.push(nota)

     }
     console.log(a)

     console.log('Digite 5 notas de 0 a 10 para o Segundo jogador :')
     for(i = 5; i > 0 ; i--)

     { var nota = rs.questionInt('Nota : ')
     b.push(nota)

     }
     console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta apenas a comparação que eu acabei fazendo durante o segundo incremento. Veja se isto te atende. 
Outra coisa, seria interessante você substituir a declaração de variavel *var* para *const* ou *let*. No caso de seu code seria *const*. Atualmente não usamos mais o *var* por questão de hoisting.

```
var rs = require("readline-sync");

var a = [];
var b = [];
var repeated = [];

var nome1 = rs.question("Digite o nome do primeiro jogador : ");
var nome2 = rs.question(" Digite o nome do segundo jogador : ");

console.log("Digite 5 notas de 0 a 10 para o Primeiro jogador :");
for (i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
  var nota = rs.questionInt("Nota : ");
  a.push(nota);
}

console.log("Digite 5 notas de 0 a 10 para o Segundo jogador :");
for (i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
  var nota = rs.questionInt("Nota : ");
  if (a.includes(nota)) repeated.push(nota); // Adicionado aqui
  b.push(nota);
}

console.log("Items repetidos: ", repeated.join());
```

Comment: valeu rodou legal, to iniciando agora mas vou dar um att nas variaveis pra não usar var mais...

Comment: Se eu fosse fazer o inverso, compara números diferentes de A e B como ficaria?